# How many of 124000 prophets were Arab?

Tags: history, prophets

Someone said that there were solely four (4) Arab prophets between those 124000 prophets (Nabis). So it was not rational for me as an actual statistics, because seemingly majority of prophets were in Arab countries… . So, I’d like to know if there is any authentic statistics to demonstrate how many of 124.000 prophets were Arab?

Comment: where did you got this number 1240000??????

Comment: The hadith you're referring to isn't authentic.

Comment: What was wrong with the old tags?  I see absolutely no reason to suddenly create two brand new tags just for this question.

Comment: Yeah yeah yeah, how did this number 124000 come into existence???? Seriously I wanted to know, I always hear that in my family, but not there in Qur'an I guess. And moreover, the prophets were sent to the whole world, it is very difficult to even know their names, so how can one say, how many were sent to Arab. These are again matters of Ghaib(unseen).

Answer (score 3):

We do not know how many prophets are there, but those who are Arab are known to us as:

## Prophet Hood

He was sent to his people A'd, the Bedouins living in the `الأحقاف` (Sand Mountains) located between Oman and Hadramout, Yemen.

[Hood http://imagecache.te3p.com/imgcache/1179a4b907b068420ac4676a86a06ead.jpg](http://imagecache.te3p.com/imgcache/1179a4b907b068420ac4676a86a06ead.jpg)

---

## Prophet Saleh

He was sent to his people Thamoud, the people living in stones between Hijaz and Tabook. These people are similar to the people of Hood in the way they constructed their villages.

[image: Thamoud]
<sub>(source: [quran-m.com](http://www.quran-m.com/firas/ar_photo/12303971592981125987_2ebef9331d.jpg))</sub>

---

## Prophet Shoaib

He was sent to his people Madyan, who use to live in Madyan, a village in Moan province to the outskirts of Alsham from the Hijaz side. Similar to the other two, their homes were constructed out of stones.

[image: Madyan]

---

## Prophet Ismael

He was sent to Jirham, where the people of Amaleek (Kanean and Amooryoon tribes) and the People of Yemen and the areas around it.

---

## Prophet Mohamed

He was sent to the humans and Jinn alike.

> قال البدوي الشنقيطي في عمود النسب: والعرب إسماعيل منهم دون ريب هود وصالح محمد شعيب.
>
> The Shanqeeti says, the Arab Prophets decedents of Ismael, Hood, Saleh, Mohamed an Shoaib.

---

**Source:**

[http://fatwa.islamweb.net](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=56981)

Comment: Uh-huh, your asnwer is relatively such as what I found in our references. Actually three of them looks common between shai and sunni view based on your answer (Prophet Muhammad(S), Hood, Saleh) / God bless you for proving such nice answers with pretty pics.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a scholar, but I've heard of this . I know Abraham (as) was told he would be the father of many nations. There is no specification on what nationality he is. Jacob (as) according to Christianity wrestled all knight with the lord and he changed his name to Is real. That would be beginning the Israel tribes. All I know I trust the prophet Muhammad (SAS) if he says their were only 4 Arab prophets then there was only 4 Arab prophets, and no more. It's best for everyone to trust in Allah and his messenger.

Comment: Can you share the Hadith that says there were only 4 Arab Prophets?

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to define Arab throughout the whole history of mankind.

Question to you: Was Adam an Arab?

If it is about the Arabic language, there is only Muhammad pbuh.
The prophet before Muhammad was Jesus, and he did not speak Arabic. Between them were more than 600 years. I hope you see that your question is a somewhat difficult one. I tend to say that there is no answer to this really unless you define appropriately the term *Arab*.

The Hadeeth is not authentic, I believe.

Comment: Uh-huh. It seems so difficult to calculate them as seemingly you mentioned like that unless we figure it out through hadith(S). Well done mate. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

```
                                    In the name of Allah
```

**There is a hadith (tradition) from the apostle of Allah (blessings of Allah be upon him and his family) that he said to Abuzar Qafari :**

> There were four Arab prophets between your prophets, Hood, Saleh,
>   Sheith and your prophet "the messenger of Allah (SAWW)"
>
> (Bahar Al Anwar, Volume 74th)

On the other hand, it is likewise discussed that the answer would be depended upon the interpretation of Arab race. Since, its number would be changed if:

- We deem Arabs to the children of Hazrat-Ismael (and after him ...)
- We deem Arabs to Sam as the son of Hazrat-Noah (and after him ...)

And so forth.

---

Reference:

- [www.hawzah.net](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/Question/View/63530/%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C-%DA%A9%D9%87-%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8-%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%86%D8%AF)
- [www.mashreghnews.ir](http://www.mashreghnews.ir/fa/news/203611/)

Comment: If with Sheith (peace be upon him) they mean the prophet also called Seth (peace be upon him) this could be a problem as this is a son or grandson of Adam AFAIK and again AFAIK (and maybe i'm wrong) Arabs are descendants of Ismail (peace be upon him)

Comment: And Allah know Best. God bless you for paying attention to that point.